# Convert Stake Key to Address

Tags: cardano-serialization-lib, cardano-address

I am tiring to use Cardano Sterilization Lib to get the Stake/Usable address from Stake Hash or Address Hash.

https://adaex.org/address/addr1q8d27ughqsqras7k9wnr4dlustzjlhadhe9rf6t3tr90u5yc4vxfxvmpr0hfktjc7md2n8er05tnurr676n6yq7khcnss8msq0/all-addresses#data

Address Hash: 01daaf711704003ec3d62ba63ab7fc82c52fdfadbe4a34e97158cafe5098ab0c9333611bee9b2e58f6daa99f237d173e0c7af6a7a203d6be27

Stake Key Hash: e198ab0c9333611bee9b2e58f6daa99f237d173e0c7af6a7a203d6be27

I saw [Convert xpub public key from ccvault to bech32 or acct_ public key](https://cardano.stackexchange.com/questions/7689/convert-xpub-public-key-from-ccvault-to-bech32-or-acct-public-key) which showed a way but I couldn't get it to work.

`wasm.StakeCredential.from_bytes(new TextEncoder().encode("98ab0c9333611bee9b2e58f6daa99f237d173e0c7af6a7a203d6be27"))`

returns  Deserialization failed in StakeCredential because: Invalid cbor: not the right type, expected `Array' byte received` Text'.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with this line:

```
wasm.StakeCredential.from_bytes(
 Buffer.from("98ab0c9333611bee9b2e58f6daa99f237d173e0c7af6a7a203d6be27", "hex")
)
```

Alternatively, you can try using `from_keyhash` method. This method expects to receive a `Ed25519KeyHash`, which you can build from the given Stake Key Hash, all in the same instruction, like this:

```
wasm.StakeCredential.from_keyhash(
 wasm.Ed25519KeyHash.from_bytes(
  Buffer.from("e198ab0c9333611bee9b2e58f6daa99f237d173e0c7af6a7a203d6be27", "hex")
 )
)
```